# Selectivity in Suzuki coupling of 2,4-dichloropyrimidine

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds, regioselectivity, organoboron-compounds

I've seen many papers (see e.g. [*Synthesis* **2010,** *16,* 2721–2724](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-0030-1258150)) in which the 4-chloro group of 2,4-dichloropyrimidine is selectively reacted under Suzuki coupling conditions. Is there any way where this regioselectivity of the coupling can be predicted?

[image: Suzuki coupling scheme]

Comment: There are the [Handy rules](https://doi.org/10.1039/B512948F) for predicting regioselectivity of cross-coupling for polyhalogenated heterocycles, based on the 1H NMR shifts, but for pyrimidine there is a general preference for cross-coupling at C-4 and C-6 which runs contrary to the Handy predictions. See also [Baran group meeting on heterocycle haloselectivity](https://www.scripps.edu/baran/images/grpmtgpdf/Gutekunst_Apr_10.pdf)